# python argparse variable name to the argument

Tags: python, argparse

im new with the python argparse , i want to make it so the usage is the following :

```
mono.py [-h] (--encrypt KEY | --decrypt KEY) [--out FILE] FILE
```

but all i could do is

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument("--encrypt",dest='key',action="store_true", help="enrycpt given a key")
group.add_argument("--decrypt",dest='key',action="store_true", help="decrypt given a key")
parser.add_argument("--out",help="if --out is specified output to the file", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("FILE", help="FILE to decrypt/encrypt")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

which gives this usage :

```
mono.py [-h] (--encrypt| --decrypt) [--out] FILE
```

can anyone explain how to link a variable KEY/FILE to the arguments?

Comment: What do you think `store_true` means?

Comment: Do you actually want `action="store_true"`, then? If you remove that, the only change you need to make is to the `--out` [metavar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar). Note that you can't tell from the resulting namespace whether the user asked you to encrypt or decrypt, which might be a problem.

Comment: Use `store` instead of `store_true`.

Comment: with store_true i wanted to check if the user has --encrypt/decrypt used. with a metavar if args.encrypt works fine aswell?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't use `action="store_true"` for options that you want to take an argument. It'll make it so that they only store `True` if the option is provided, or `False` if it isn't. See the documentation for [action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action).

Next, use a [metavar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar) instead of a [dest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest), as [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) pointed out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64978098/python-argparse-variable-name-to-the-argument#comment114877473_64978098):

> Note that you can't tell from the resulting namespace whether the user asked you to encrypt or decrypt, which might be a problem.

Lastly, use a metavar for `--out` as well.

Here's an example with the `FILE` argument and help text removed for simplicity:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument("--encrypt", metavar='KEY')
group.add_argument("--decrypt", metavar='KEY')
parser.add_argument("--out", metavar="FILE")

parser.print_usage()
```

Output:

```
usage: tmp.py [-h] (--encrypt KEY | --decrypt KEY) [--out FILE]
```

Example parsing:

```
for s in '--encrypt k', '--decrypt k', '--encrypt k --out f':
   print(parser.parse_args(s.split()))
```

```
Namespace(decrypt=None, encrypt='k', out=None)
Namespace(decrypt='k', encrypt=None, out=None)
Namespace(decrypt=None, encrypt='k', out='f')
```

Example usage of encrypt and decrypt (pseudocode):

```
file = args.file
if args.encrypt is not None:
    key = args.encrypt
    encrypt(file, key)
elif args.decrypt is not None:
    key = args.decrypt
    decrypt(file, key)
else:
    error('This should never happen')
```

This could probably be written a bit more eloquently. For example you could make `KEY` a required positional argument instead of an argument to `--encrypt`/`--decrypt`.

Comment: thanks for pointing that i should use a metavar , i uses the store true because i wanted to know if the user has used --encrypt or --decrypt . now that they are storeed in metavar how to check that? does  args.encrypt do the trick?

Comment: @chedli Yes, exactly. I added an example.

Comment: thank you very much , this woks fine for me and i understood for the first time how argparse code actually works :)